# How to disable the back button for all pages of QWizard?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwizard, qwizardpage

I want to disable all back buttons from my application. I found a solution only for the first and last page, but I can't disable it for all the pages.

```
self.setOption(QWizard.NoBackButtonOnStartPage)
self.setOption(QWizard.NoBackButtonOnLastPage)
                    or
self.setOption(QWizard.DisabledBackButtonOnLastPage)
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a new button layout without BackButton using [`setButtonLayout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#setButtonLayout):

```py
self.setButtonLayout(
    [
        QWizard.Stretch,
        QWizard.NextButton,
        QWizard.FinishButton,
        QWizard.CancelButton,
    ]
)
```